# How to configure 3rd parties for the sextante plugin in qgis?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sextante-qgis-plugin

I'm currently exploring the enourmous potencial that the sextante plugin for qgis has to offer. The model builder will surelly be a very handy tool.

The problem is I'm not beeing able to run 3rd party (like SAGA or Orfeo). I know I have to configure the paths, but i'm not sure how.

I did it like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDcAJ.png) but still don't get tools running.

[image]

I'm getting this error:

[image]

ERROR with SAGA:

```
global name 'false' is not defined Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\vbnunes/.qgis/python/plugins\sextante\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 115, in execute     self.processAlgorithm(progress)   
File "C:\Users\vbnunes/.qgis/python/plugins\sextante\saga\SagaAlgorithm.py", line 153, in processAlgorithm     self.calculateResamplingExtent()   
File "C:\Users\vbnunes/.qgis/python/plugins\sextante\saga\SagaAlgorithm.py", line 109, i
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: I was getting this kind of error for most tools (not SAGA though) constantly under OSX with QGIS 1.8 and SEXTANTE 1.07 - but the nightly build (QGIS dev 2.0) includes SEXTANTE 1.08 and it seems to work much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the output of SAGA in the SEXTANTE history (in the INFO branch you will find both the commands used by SEXTANTE to call SAGA and the SAGA output). Could you please paste that here so we can see what is happening and help you?

Regards

Victor

Comment: Check my update in the Question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set "OTB command line tools folder" as "E:\OSGeo4W\bin".

Regards
Leonardo Lami

Comment: I think C:\OSGeo4W\bin should do better for the asker.